# How to make a legend is horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, infragistics, ignite-ui

Please tell us how to make a horizontal legend.

And here are the results:

[image]

But I want this:
[image]

I have the following code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

        //$(function () {
        function getJson() {
            var result = [];
            $.ajax({
                url: "WebService1.asmx/GetJson3",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        item = {
                            "company": value.BusinessUnitName,
                            "revenue": value.QTY_Case,
                            "expenses": value.QTY_Case_Target,
                            "cos": value.QTY_Case_LY
                        }
                        result.push(item);
                    });
                },
                async: false,
            });

            $("#columnChart").igDataChart({
                width: "280px",
                height: "200px",
                dataSource: result,
                legend: {
                    element: "columnLegend"
                },

                title: "title",
                subtitle: "subtitle",

                axes: [{
                    name: "xAxis",
                    type: "categoryX",
                    //label: "company",
                    labelTopMargin: 5,
                    gap: 0.4,  
                    overlap: 0.0,
 
                }, {
                    name: "yAxis",
                    type: "numericY",
                    maximumValue: 250000,
                    interval: 50,
                    minimumValue: 0,
                    formatLabel: function (val) {
                        var bVal = (val / 10000),
                        rounded = Math.round(bVal * 100) / 100;
                        return rounded + "M";
                    }
                }],
                series: [{
                    name: "series1",
                    title: "revenue",
                    type: "column",
                    isTransitionInEnabled: true,
                    xAxis: "xAxis",
                    yAxis: "yAxis",
                    valueMemberPath: "revenue"
                }, {
                    name: "series2",
                    title: "expenses",
                    type: "column",
                    isTransitionInEnabled: true,
                    xAxis: "xAxis",
                    yAxis: "yAxis",
                    valueMemberPath: "expenses"
                }, {
                    name: "series3",
                    title: "cos",
                    type: "column",
                    isTransitionInEnabled: true,
                    xAxis: "xAxis",
                    yAxis: "yAxis",
                    valueMemberPath: "cos"
                },
                ]
            });

        }
        $(function () {
            getJson();
        });

    </script>
```

I hope to be guided.
Thank You,
Best regard

Comment: I'm not sure what the HTML output looks like, but you might be able to set the three elements (revenue, expenses, cos) to each have a `display` of `inline-block` in CSS. Since you have the CSS tag on here.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=igDataChart+horizontal+legend the first result is someone else asking the same question, to which they got an answer

Comment: Thanks to Sam and  Andrew Bone
It was very good advice. I just added some code As they guide you. It's success.
Best regard

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered in the link provided by Andrew Bone. I will post the answer here as well so it's visible.

Make the table rows belonging to the legend to be displayed as `inline-block`.

```
#columnLegend tr {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Another suggestion I have based on the code that you've provided is to not make the `$.ajax` call sync. Just initialize the `igDataChart` inside the success callback.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "WebService1.asmx/GetJson3",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            item = {
                "company": value.BusinessUnitName,
                "revenue": value.QTY_Case,
                "expenses": value.QTY_Case_Target,
                "cos": value.QTY_Case_LY
            }
            result.push(item);
            initChart();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: hello Konstantin Dinev, 
 
Thanks  for advice.
I added code:
#columnLegend tr {display: inline-block;}.
Where <style> </ style>. Its success and visibility.